# Rapidminer - replace missing values with text

Tags: rapidminer, data-cleaning

Just starting out with Rapidminer ans wondering how to replace missing values with the a text value. For instance the values in the field are "Y", "N" and missing.

I want the missing values to be "Did Not Answer" or "DNA" or something. I see how to make the values 0.

Do I need to set attribute types before hand to allow text values in the replenishment value slot?

Answer (score 1):

The replenishment value option for replace missing values operator can do it.